# The view counter for very popular questions (100k+) doesn't have the correct color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Here is an example of [Jon Skeet's questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions&sort=views).

[image: view counters are not colored]

Comment: +1. And same problem on any SE site with the recently updated design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will go on live after our next production build.

Comment: While you're at it.. can you push the new profile page to StackOverflow..?! Thanks :P

Comment: @Lipis we definitely plan to soon(tm)!

Comment: Looking forward... keep it up.. I know I'm not the only one waiting for it :D